# Is there such a HTML DOM event?

Tags: events, insert, dom

I need a HTML DOM event which can be bound to HTML DOM document and will be run when any HTML DOM element is inserted to DOM document?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What I mean is HTML DOM. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should look Mutation DOM Events

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Events#Mutation_DOM_events
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference

but be aware of each one will not trigger in every browser, you should use different events in different browsers.

[here is a jsfiddle live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/newtang/kysTm/15/)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference) you can find the list of all DOM events.